# Adjust caption position

Tags: graphics

I have adapted code from Springer's SVMONO which allows to use the command `\sidecaption` inside a normal figure environment. The caption is then placed besides the figure instead of below it. Also, there is the option [t] which puts the sidecaption on the bottom. Example:

[image]
[image]

I read some typographic rules which say that the caption should be at the top if the figure is at the top of the page, and the caption should be on the bottom if the figure is near to the bottom of the page. I like sidecaptions but when writing my document, I usually don't know in advance whether my figure will be on top or on the bottom of a page. I wonder whether there is some macro technique which checks the position of a figure on the page, and then depending whether the figure is nearer to the top or bottom, transforms a `\sidecaption` into a `\sidecaption[t]` ?

Comment: The easiest solution is to use tikzpagenodes to check if the top is above or below the center of the text area.  An mwe would be useful here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not having an mwe or access to SVMONO, I created my own \SideCaption macro.  This version compares the center of the figure vs. the center of the text area.  I wasn't sure about the odd/even page rules.  BTW, it takes two runs for the `tikzpicture` to know where it is on the page.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{mwe}% for \lipsum and \blindtext

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\SideCaption}[2]% #1 = image, #2 = caption
{\sbox0{#1}%
 \sbox1{\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr \textwidth-\wd0-\columnsep}
   \captionsetup{singlelinecheck=off,skip=0pt}%
   \caption{#2}%
 \end{minipage}}
 \@tempdima=\dimexpr \ht0+\dp0\relax% could be a tabular
 \@tempdimb=\dimexpr \ht1+\dp1\relax%
 \ifdim\@tempdima<\@tempdimb
   \raisebox{-\height}{\usebox1}\hfill\raisebox{-\height}{\usebox0}
 \else
   \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
     \node(frame) [minimum height=\@tempdima,text width=\textwidth,inner sep=0pt] {};
     \pgfextracty{\@tempdimb}{\pgfpointdiff{\pgfpointanchor{current page text area}{center}}%
       {\pgfpointanchor{frame}{center}}}%
     \ifoddpageoroneside
       \ifdim\@tempdimb>0pt% above center
         \node[below right,inner sep=0pt] at (frame.north west) {\usebox1};
       \else
         \node[above right,inner sep=0pt] at (frame.south west) {\usebox1};
       \fi
       \node[left,inner sep=0pt] at (frame.east) {\usebox0};
     \else
       \ifdim\@tempdimb>0pt% above center
         \node[below left,inner sep=0pt] at (frame.north east) {\usebox1};
       \else
         \node[above left,inner sep=0pt] at (frame.south east) {\usebox1};
       \fi
       \node[right,inner sep=0pt] at (frame.west) {\usebox0};
     \fi
   \end{tikzpicture}
 \fi}
\makeatother

\def\bottomfraction{0.7}% allow large bottom figures

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[t]
\SideCaption{\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image}}{Top caption}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[b]
\SideCaption{\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image}}{Bottom caption}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[t]
\SideCaption{\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image}}{Top caption}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[b]
\SideCaption{\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image}}{Bottom caption}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[t]
\SideCaption{\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image}}{\blindtext}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[1-5]

\end{document}
```

[image: two pages]